# generic type which implement a generic interface with more than one type

Tags: c#, generics

I have this interface:

```
interface a<A, B>
{
    A retA();
    B retB();
}
```

and I would like to create a *generic method* that takes a type which implements this interface.

```
private void fa<T>() where T : a<A, B>, new(){ code}
```

This line doesn't work (*compile time error*):

> the type or namespace A could not be found, the type or namespace B could not be found

Thank you for your help

Comment: "(this line doesn't work)" this is an amazingly insufficient problem description. Please be more precise. Do you get any error messages? if yes what are they? What did you expect? and what actually is the resulting outcome of your code? up to now the posted code is compileable and there is no evident problem with it. Without further information we need to close this question as **unclear**

Comment: You have *three* generic parameters: `A, B, C` that's why the declaration should be `private void fa<T, A, B>() where T : a<A, B>, new(){ code}` or you should put types instead of `A` and `B`: `private void fa<T>() where T : a<string, int>, new(){ code}`

Comment: Ok I think it's the good way to do that. thank you. Can you please put your answer in a answer instead of of comment so that i could accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer given by  Dmitry Bychenko :

```
fa<T, A, B>() where T : a<A, B>, new(){ code}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have *three* generic parameters (`A`, `B`, `T`) within `fa` method; each of them should be either *declared* or *resolved*; there are several ways to do it, e.g.

```
  public class Sample1<A, B> {
    // Class declares A and B; method declares T
    private void fa<T>() where T : a<A, B>, new() {
      // Code
    }
  }

  public class Sample2 {
    // Method declares all three generic types: A, B and T
    private void fa<T, A, B>() where T : a<A, B>, new() {
      // Code 
    }
  }

  public class Sample3 {
    // Method declares T; A and B are resolved (explict types: string and int)
    private void fa<T>() where T : a<string, int>, new() {
      // Code
    }
  }

  public class Sample4<A> {
    // Class declares A; method declares T; B is resolved (explicit type int)
    private void fa<T>() where T : a<A, int>, new() {
      // Code
    }
  }
```

Etc.